# How to enable voice-activation of S Voice when in car?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, voice-command, voice-recognition, s-voice

I am only interested in using **S Voice** with voice activation (i.e. "Hi Galaxy!") when driving.

Is there any way to activate **S Voice** when I plug my **Samsung Galaxy S3** into my car's charger?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the app [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). Also the free app [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&feature=search_result) may also be able to do this.

Tasker and Llama automate tasks on your phone. So you can have them say *IF* this condition (car charger plugged in) *THEN* do something (activate SVoice).

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on how these apps solve the problem?

Comment: Tasker and llama automate tasks on your phone. So you can have them say IF this condition(car charger plugged in) THEN do something (activate SVoice)

Comment: I took the freedom to integrate this with your answer, so it is better recognized as part of it. Thanks for the update!